# SelectedImageTintColor of UITabBar is getting reset after MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

After `MFMailComposeViewController` was called. The `SelectedImageTintColor` of `UITabBar` is changed and back to dark gray.

I read that this is some kind of a bug in IOS 7.1

I tried

```
[[self.tabBarController tabBar] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

in 
`mailComposeController` `didFinishWithResult`

But nothing changed.

Workarounds?

Comment: always use `UIAppearance` when you can over styling directly components

Comment: OK... tried [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; - still nothing